# Symfony 3 Translations Custom Domain

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to add custom domain into the project.
I have regions.locale.yaml file.

I'm trying load it in twig:

```
{{'united.kingdom'|trans|raw}}
```

But this doesn't work. 
I think it has to be somehow declared that this file exists.

I found this in documentation:

```
// ...
$translator->addLoader('xlf', new XliffFileLoader());

$translator->addResource('xlf', 'messages.fr.xlf', 'fr_FR');
$translator->addResource('xlf', 'admin.fr.xlf', 'fr_FR', 'admin');
$translator->addResource(
    'xlf',
    'navigation.fr.xlf',
    'fr_FR',
    'navigation'
);
```

But where should I put this to declare my regions.locale.yaml files globally?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Symfony Standard, you don't have to declare your translation files, you just put them in **app/Resources/translations**.

The key is that when you want to translate using your custom domain, you just specify your domain, like this :

```
{{'united.kingdom'|trans({}, 'regions')|raw }}
```

or somewhere else in your code :

```
$translator->trans('united.kingdom', [], 'regions');
```